# Fitting GridPane JavaFx

Tags: javafx, pane

I've been trying to select the most appropriate Pane which would fit my elements. I have tried FlowPane and GridPane, but I've had the same result.

[Screenshot with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxxu2.png)
What I want a result is to place the playerCards grid which is on column 1 row 1 straight under the playerInfo grid which is on column 1, row 0. This is not happening because the height of the element's height on column 0, row 0 is bigger. And all elements on the next row are positioned according to this. So basically my goal is to remove the space between the element with red background and the white background.

```
private Node getTop() {
    GridPane container = new GridPane();
    FlowPane topp = new FlowPane();
    topp.setMinHeight(200);
    GridPane playerInfo = new GridPane();
    playerInfo.setHgap(125.0);
    playerInfo.setVgap(5.0);
    playerInfo.setPadding(new Insets(10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 50.0));

    //most left here
    GridPane legend = new GridPane();
    legend.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
    legend.setVgap(2.0);
    Label[] treasureTypes = new Label[7];
    treasureTypes[0] = new Label(" - Diamonds           5pts");
    treasureTypes[1] = new Label(" - Rubies                5pts");
    treasureTypes[3] = new Label(" - Pearls                 3pts");
    treasureTypes[2] = new Label(" - Gold Bars           4pts");
    treasureTypes[4] = new Label(" - Barrels of Rum   2pts");
    treasureTypes[5] = new Label(" - Black card");
    treasureTypes[6] = new Label(" - Red card");

    for (int x = 0; x < treasureTypes.length; ++x) {
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 1:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 2:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/pearls.jpg")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 3:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/gold_bar.png")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 4:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 5:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png")), 0, x);
                break;
            case 6:
                legend.add(new ImageView(new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png")), 0, x);
                break;
        }
        legend.add(treasureTypes[x], 1, x);
    }
    legend.setPadding(new Insets(10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 50.0));

    //top.getChildren().add(left);
    //right buttons here
    Button rules = new Button("Rules");
    Button idk = new Button("Chance Card References");
    VBox rightButtons = new VBox();
    rightButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    rightButtons.setMinWidth(200.0);
    rightButtons.getChildren().addAll(rules, idk);

    Label playerNames[] = new Label[4];
    Label playerCoords[] = new Label[4];
    Label playerMoveRange[] = new Label[4];
    Label playerHomeTown[] = new Label[4];

    Player pl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {

        pl = gameEngine.getPlayer(x);

        playerNames[x] = new Label();
        playerCoords[x] = new Label();
        playerMoveRange[x] = new Label();
        playerHomeTown[x] = new Label();

        //highlight the current player nickname
        if (pl.getNickname().equals(gameEngine.getCurrentPlayer().getNickname())) {
            playerNames[x].setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            //this is for reseting the color i.e the color is currently green
            playerNames[x].setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
        playerNames[x].setText("Player :" + pl.getNickname());
        playerCoords[x].setText("Coordinates : ("
                + Integer.toString(pl.getShip().getCoordinates().getColumn() + 1)
                + ", " + Integer.toString(pl.getShip().getCoordinates().getRow() + 1) + ")");

        playerMoveRange[x].setText("Player move range: " + pl.getMovementRange());
        playerHomeTown[x].setText("Home town: " + pl.getShip().getHomeTown().getName());

        playerInfo.add(playerNames[x], x, 0);
        playerInfo.add(playerCoords[x], x, 1);
        playerInfo.add(playerMoveRange[x], x, 2);
        playerInfo.add(playerHomeTown[x], x, 3);
    }
    GridPane playerCards = new GridPane();
    int numCards = 0;
    int cardColor, cardVal;

    for (Card c : gameEngine.getCurrentPlayer().getCards()) {
        cardColor = (c.getColor()) ? 1 : 0;
        cardVal = c.getValue();
        Image cardImg = null;

        switch (cardColor) {
            case 0:
                switch (cardVal) {
                    case 1:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                switch (cardVal) {
                    case 1:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cardImg = new Image("group/project/images/diamond.png");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        playerCards.add(new ImageView(cardImg), numCards, 0);
        ++numCards;
    }
    playerCards.setPadding(new Insets(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 75.0));

    playerCards.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
    playerInfo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    playerInfo.setMaxHeight(100);
    container.add(legend, 0, 0);
    container.add(playerInfo, 1, 0);
    container.add(rightButtons, 2, 0);
    container.add(playerCards, 1, 1);

    return container;
}
```

This is the whole function which returns a Node - GridPane and then is set as top of borderPane. i.e borderPane.setTop(getTop());

Comment: Try `GridPane.setValignment(playerInfo, VPos.BOTTOM);`.

Comment: This wasn't helpful